# Which follows an uncountable noun of multiple things, singular or plural verb?

Tags: verb-forms, uncountable-nouns

Which of these sentences is better?

> The water **usage** of Alice and Bob **are** different.
>
> The water **usage** of Alice and Bob **is** different.

The first one seems better because we can treat two uncountable nouns (*Alice's water usage* and *Bob's water usage*) as two things. But is either of the sentences better than the other?

Here let's assume "usage" is an uncountable noun.

Comment: I would say _"Bob's and my water usages are different."_  I would never say _"The water usage of I is....."_ OR _"The water usage of me is....."_  The only similar construction I can imagine using is _"That water usage of mine is ...."_  Since I cannot possibly imagine using the phrase ""The water usage of Bob [and I/me]..."_  I am having a difficult time coming up with a conjugation of any subsequent verbs.

Comment: As Native English speakers, we put ourselves through many contortions to avoid the decision about whether to use a pronoun in the objective case, particularly the first person pronoun. It's one of the corners into which the "rules" of grammar have painted us. The "right" thing sounds wrong, and the "wrong" thing doesn't sound much better. One result in dialect is the use of **all** objective pronouns as subjective: "Me and them are going..."

Comment: I would never say "water usage OF Bob". Agree with Adam: Bob's and my water usages are different. But, more usual: My water usage and Bob's water usage ARE different.

Comment: @Lambie Of course no native speaker would phrase the thought in that way. The OP's question, though, is not "What would Adam or Lambie say?" He wants to know if either sentence is _correct_, and when mass nouns and pronouns are involved, correctness and prevalence may diverge.

Comment: @P. E. Dante In any even, of I is incorrect. It has nothing to do with prevalence. It is an outright mistake. Do I **do** myself clear? Why let him assume that water usage OF I is right at all? It really isn't about prevalence. Of I is not "prevalent". And you actually take it seriously in your first comment  in your answer...

Comment: *The water usage of I* cannot be assumed or considered to be correct. No native speaker I know would ever say that. Likewise, *the water usage of me* is not something that any native speaker  I know would ever say. One can say *The water usage of mine* or, simply, *my water usage*.

Comment: The issue with the pronouns is when they come together, linked by *and*. Thus the grammaticality of *The water usage of Bob and I* is judged to be acceptable by some speakers precisely because of this: *of Bob **and** I*. Compare: *between Bob **and** I* (which is fairly widely used).

Comment: @AlanCarmack Thanks to P.E.Dant and Lambie and Alan for pointing out that "sth of I (or me)" is incorrect (or not prevalent). I have revised the question to avoid this issue.

Comment: Your question has changed so much from the original version that it is asking something different.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of issues here.

It is not idiomatic to say "the water usage *of me*" or "the water usage of him". We say "my|your|his|her|our|their water usage".

The hat of me (no)
My hat  (yes)

For that reason, native speakers naturally *tend* to avoid phrases like "the water usage of him and me" or "the water usage of Bob and me".  Does that mean *no* native speaker would ever say "The water usage of Bob and me is different"? No, it does not; but such usage is an outlier statistically.

A native speaker with a developed sense of grammatical foresight would not make "water usage" the subject of the sentence, because if they do, they get into hot water when trying to express the idea that the thing is not something shared but two things which are distinct and being compared; and that problem persists even if the noun is countable:

The friends of Bob and me...

Are we talking about Bob's friends *as distinct from* my friends, or about our *mutual* friends?

The water usage(s) of Bob and me...

Are you and Bob roommates or housemates?  Neighbors?  Making a usually non-count noun countable helps to clarify, but there is still some dissonance: "the hat of me".

To express the idea of distinct comparands clearly, we state each comparand separately:

> Bob's water usage and mine vary considerably.
>
> Bob's water usage and my own vary considerably.
>
> My water usage and Bob's vary considerably.
>
> My own water usage and Bob's vary considerably.
>
> Bob's water usage and my water usage are not all that different.

Comment: +1 for "grammatical foresight," @TRomano. I was grasping at such a term in my comments and couldn't get hold of it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct version is

> The water usage [of Bob and I]<sup>1</sup> **is** different

Here, Bob and I are in a prepositional phrase. The sentence's subject is the singular *usage*.

However, *usage* (like *uses*) is also used as a count noun. See [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/usage); so I don't see anything wrong with

> The water usages of Bob and I **are** different.

To answer in general, a singular uncountable noun will take a singular verb, even if the noun refers to "multiple things." There are very few nouns in English that can only be used as uncountable or mass nouns, but the following is an example:

> The fun that Bob and Henry and George and Sue had at the water park **was** incredible.

This narrows down to

> The fun was incredible.

You can use a prepositional phrase, as in your sentence; for example:

> The fun of the summer and spring and fall **is** not as much as that of winter.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some speakers insist that the correct version of this prepositional phrase should be *of Bob and me*, just like the correct version would be *of me*; but you will hear native speakers use *of Bob and I* also. On a test, I would put *of Bob and me*, because that is what most tests want to hear.

On the issue of which pronoun to use when they are connected with *and*, see [Case and coordination](https://books.google.com/books?id=AMAgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=%22Case+in+coordinations%22&source=bl&ots=mLFS_ghT3u&sig=8h1eZxOcObtBi7CG6qrNqDyHuqI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV8_OFsabOAhUB7iYKHS6lDGYQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=%22Case%20in%20coordinations%22&f=false), a section in *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* by Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey K. Pullum.

Comment: "Shouldn't **of** take the objective case of **I**?" is a common question.  There are really two questions here, one of which is a common source of confusion for learners: the objective case of the first person pronoun and how/when to use it - and why "the water usages of I" would never be heard or written. I was about to send the questioner [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/27704/37009).

Comment: @P.E.Dant The user asks only one question, about uncountable or mass nouns, and I am afraid the discussion about the pronouns is bound to be distracting and confusing. Nevertheless, I've put in a footnote.

Comment: It sounds a little strange to me. If "The water usage of Bob and I is different" and "Bob's water usage and my water usage are different" are both correct, and they have the same meaning, then they seem not consistent since one uses the singular verb while the other uses the plural verb. Thanks for pointing out "of me" and the plural form "usages", although they are not under my consideration here.

Comment: @tankgong Well, it sounds a little strange to _us_, too, and we are native speakers! Alan's answer to your question is excellent. Read it carefully to understand why the plural and singular verb forms are used. If you want to learn more about "me" and "I" and when to use them, the link he provides is a fine place to start.

Comment: I think if "The water usage of Bob and I is different" is correct and clear, then its meaning is different from that of "Bob's water usage and my water usage are different"? Although "Bob and I" is intended to mean "multiple things", it will be understood as one thing in the first sentence? If this is the case, then the second sentence should be used to express the meaning that "Bob's water usage is different from my water usage".

Comment: To follow up, "The water usage of Bob and I is different" sounds strange because "one thing" cannot be different (from itself) and only "multiple things" can be different (from each other), and "is" sounds meaning "one thing".

Comment: Water usage by Bob and me. I would never say OF here.

Comment: @tankgong The subject of _The water usage of Bob and I is different_ is the mass expression "water usage" - it _is_ "one thing," and this takes the singular verb form. It's all right there in the answer - read it carefully.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I see the sentence is correct and "The water usage of Bob and I" is "one thing", but the meaning of this sentence alone (without any context) is strange, since only "multiple things" can be different (from each other) and "one thing" cannot be different (from itself).

Comment: @tankgong As long as you understand _why_ it is correct grammatically, you can do as most native speakers would if they were forced to express it that way—which is to **refuse to say it!** Instead we would say _My water usage and Bob's are different,_ _Bob and I have different water usage_ or even _Me and Bob have different water usage._

Comment: @P.E.Dant I see your point. Thanks for these examples.